# ERROR COLLATION 'utf8_unicode_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' when running mysql on Mac

Tags: mysql, macos

I am trying to start mysql server on my Mac (installed version: 5.7 using brew).
I am getting:

`. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/logfile.local.pid`
Looking at the log file, I see the following logs:

```
2021-07-13T20:36:18.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2021-07-13T20:36:18.937962Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2021-07-13T20:36:18.938598Z 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2021-07-13T20:36:18.938693Z 0 [Note] /usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.34) starting as process 29074 ...
2021-07-13T20:36:18.942868Z 0 [ERROR] COLLATION 'utf8_unicode_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'
2021-07-13T20:36:18.942942Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2021-07-13T20:36:18.942974Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2021-07-13T20:36:18.943092Z 0 [Note] /usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Server isn't even started so I am not sure what is the cause of this. Mysqldump then would show me `mysqldump: Got error: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61) when trying to connect` which I assume is due to the server itself not running

Answer (score 1):

`utf8_*` collations only work for `utf8` character set.

If you use the `utf8mb4` character set, you must use a collation like `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` (or another collation matching `utf8mb4_*`).

Comment: So not sure even where it's coming from. I was not even able to start the mysql server

Comment: Check your `my.cnf` options file.